# Finding all the minima in a unconstrained minimization problem

Tags: optimization

I've just read a textbook stating that the first order condition $\frac{df}{dx} = 0$ and second order sufficient condition $\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2} \gt 0$ of unconstrained minimization will find the all the local minima.

Is this statement right?

Using only these conditions will miss the minimum point in case such as $f(x)=x^4$.

I'm confused...

Comment: Certainly $f^\prime = 0$ and $f^{\prime\prime} > 0$ fail to discover the point $x=0$ for $f(x) = x^4$. Does your book define a local minimum in some peculiar way such that "flat" minima like this aren't "local minima"?

Comment: No. It does not say about that kind of restriction.  Thank you.

Comment: The statement would appear to be false then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a case where the test is inconclusive (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test)). In that case (according to the same source) you can use further criteria such as the Taylor expansion to determine the behaviour of $f(x)$ near any critical point. In, the case of the $f(x)$ that you mention:

1. 1st order condition $$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}=4x^3$$ and this is equal to zero we find that $x=0$. Thus $x=0$ is a critical point.
2. 2nd order condition $$\frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x^2}|_{x=0}\large=12x^2|_{x=0}=12\cdot0=0$$ So in this case the test is *inconclusive.*

But, since $f(x)=x^4$ is always nonnegative and for $x=0$ you have that $f(0)=0$ then you obtain that way the minimum.

Comment: So... the statement is wrong. isn't it?

Comment: @user89855 No it is not. Notice that is says *sufficient* condition and not *necessary*. Sufficient means that when it holds, then it is ok, but necessary means that if does not hold then it is not ok

Comment: The first sentence in the question.

Comment: @user89855 Yes, ok. Is the explanation ok, see the previous comment, I edited it.

Comment: So...  Using first order condition and second order sufficient condition CANNOT find ALL minima, right?

Comment: @user89855 Right.

Comment: @user89855 you are welcome mate!